# backbone,in subview page click event is not working for button

Tags: backbone.js

backbone,in subview page click event is not working for button ".rdp-sitting-more"

First of all, i have an view called main.view.js.
I need to create a table where each "tr" value i will get from model.so i think to create a subview for each "tr",that will help me to bind model for each "tr" value.so,i create a "processCollection" function.

Now the issue is in click event is not working for button ".rdp-sitting-more". which is called in "tr-subview.view.js"

```
1.main.view.js

            createSubview: function (model) {
                if (!this.subView) {
                    this.subView = [];
                }
                var element = $('<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>');
                model["associates"] = this.appointmentdetailsModel.get("associates")[0];
                var sittingObj = {};
                _.each(model.sittings, function (sitting, index) {
                    sitting["index"] = sitting;
                    sittingObj[index] = sitting;
                });
                model["sittingsObj"] = sittingObj;
                this.$el.find("tbody").append(element);
                this.subView.push(new appointmentdetailsView({
                    el: element,
                    "model": model
                }));
            },

       processCollection: function (options, appointmentdetailsModel) {
                _.each(this.appointmentdetailsModel.get("orders"), function (Data) {
                    this.createSubview(Data);
                }, this);
            },

2.tr-subview.view.js

  events:{
        "click .rdp-sitting-more": "moreSitting",
}

moreSitting: function(){
  alert("moresitting")
}

<tr class="sitting" colspan="2">
   <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-info rdp-sitting-more" data-value="" style="margin:10px 0">
        <i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        Add
    </button></td>
</tr>

Could you please tell me what might be the issue?Why it's not binding the click event
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]..?

Comment: How do you render your subview? Could you show whole code for the subview? Why do you create element in the createSubview function?